# SQL query for minimal distinct set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of products and another table of specific listings of these products.

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (id INT AUTOINCREMENT);
CREATE TABLE listings (
  id INT AUTOINCREMENT,
  product INT REFERENCES products(id),
  vendor INT
)
```

I want to select listings for a set of products in such way that they are sold by minimal count of different vendors. As an example:

| id | product | vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |

For products `(1,2,3)` I expect to get ids `(1,4,5)`. Is there a way to achieve this just using SQL? Or should I simply use multiple queries and combine the results elsewhere?

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT ` doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, you need something like serial or even better, GENERATED ALWAYS. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: This looks like a variant of the knapsack problem: find which vendors to include to both minimize the number of distinct vendors included and maximize the number of products in the sack (by including them all). Unless someone can prove my previous sentence wrong, I would say your best bet is to combine the results elsewhere (the knapsack problem has no known polynomial algorithm to solve it -> definitely not something you want to program in SQL).

Comment: @Atmo that seems to be right. Now that I look at it, those multiple queries I imagined before would not work anyway

Comment: @Atmo you are completely right. This problem is apparently called Set Cover Problem and is NP hard. If you copy your comment into an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately and as I explained in comments, what you are trying to solve looks like a NP-complete problem, which you have correctly identified as the [set-cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

This means that you cannot solve the general case in polynomial time.

**Conclusion**:
Let alone maintainabilty of complex SQL queries, you probably do not want to run anything with exponantial complexity on a database; I recommend you compute the solution elsewhere, using a language and an algorithm more suitable for the task than SQL can do.
Finding an approximation of the solution can be done in polynomial time (explained in the [link above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm)). That could theoretically be done using not-too-complex SQL queries (possibly using one of the queries posted as answers, I have not checked) but even then, I would not recommend that path; better doing it outside of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive query to get all possible combinations. In your case IDs (1,3,5), (1,4,5), (2,3,5) and (2,4,5). Then check the distinct number of vendors per set, take the one with the lowest number of vendors and show the rows.

Here are my steps:

1. I number the products, so if I have products 10, 20 and 30, they get the indexes 1, 2 and 3, and so I can go from one product to the next by adding one to the index.
2. I use a recursive CTE, to get all ID combinations. As this is recursive, I'll get the complte series like (1,3,5), but also the incomplete ones (1), (1,3), etc. I remember the IDs and the vendors in arrays.
3. I pick the rows with the largest arrays, i.e. the complete ones (1,3,5), (1,4,5), (2,3,5) and (2,4,5).
4. I pick the one with the lowest number of distinct values. (In case of a tie, I'll pick one ID set arbitrarily.)
5. I select the rows for the IDs of my best set.

The query:

```
with recursive
  prep as
  (
    select l.*, dense_rank() over (order by product) as pidx
    from listings l
  ),
  series(ids, vendors, pidx) as
  (
    select
      array[id] as ids,
      array[vendor] as vendors,
      1
    from prep
    where pidx = 1
    union all
    select
      array_append(s.ids, p.id),
      array_append(s.vendors, p.vendor),
      s.pidx + 1
    from series s
    join prep p on p.pidx = s.pidx + 1
  ),
  complete as
  (
    select ids, vendors
    from series
    order by rank() over (order by cardinality(ids) desc)
    fetch first row with ties
  ),
  best as
  (
    select ids, vendors
    from complete
    order by (select cardinality(array_agg(distinct vendor))
              from unnest(vendors) t(vendor))
    fetch first row only
  )
select *
from listings
where id in (select unnest(ids) from best)
order by id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/uMqMs0xn